# Select distinct with order by runs OK when copied to db, but fails when run from application

Tags: hibernate, sql-order-by, distinct, criteria-api

I have a query which runs OK when I copy it from application console, but fails with an error in application:
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list.

But when I look at the query I see that column I order by is in select list.

Method which creates query by spec (notice ordery by and distinct)

```java
   private CriteriaQuery<Tuple> createSearchQuery(Specification<Node> spec, String searchQuery) {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

        CriteriaQuery<Tuple> queryForNode = builder.createTupleQuery();
        Root<Node> nodeRoot = queryForNode.from(Node.class);
        Join<Node,FTSDocument> join = nodeRoot.join(Node_.document);

        Expression orderyBy = builder.function(
            "ts_rank",
            Double.class,
            builder.function("to_tsvector", Object.class, join.get(FTSDocument_.document)),
            builder.function("plainto_tsquery",Object.class,builder.literal(searchQuery))
        );

        queryForNode
            .multiselect(nodeRoot, orderyBy)
            .distinct(true)
            .where(spec.toPredicate(nodeRoot, queryForNode, builder))
            .orderBy(builder.desc(orderyBy));
        return queryForNode;
    }
```

Main method:

```
    public Page<Node> findDistinctBySpec(Specification<Node> spec, String searchQuery, Pageable pageable) {

        // Get page content
        List<Tuple> resultList = entityManager.createQuery(createSearchQuery(spec, searchQuery))
            .setFirstResult(pageable.getPageNumber() * pageable.getPageSize())
            .setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize())
            .getResultList();

        List<Node> nodes = resultList.stream().map(tuple-> tuple.get(0,Node.class)).collect(Collectors.toList());

        // Get total count of matched results
        TypedQuery<Long> typedQueryForCount = entityManager.createQuery(createCountQuery(spec));
        Long totalCount = typedQueryForCount.getSingleResult();

        return new PageImpl<>(nodes, pageable, totalCount);
    }
```

Generated query is below and when i copy it to a database and set all parameters instead of question marks - it works OK.
Hibernate:

```sql
    select
        distinct node0_."id" as col_0_0_,
        ts_rank(to_tsvector(ftsdocumen1_."document"),
        plainto_tsquery(?)) as col_1_0_,
        node0_."id" as id1_7_,
        node0_."created_by" as created_2_7_,
        node0_."created_date" as created_3_7_,
        node0_."last_modified_by" as last_mod4_7_,
        node0_."last_modified_date" as last_mod5_7_,
        node0_."alias" as alias6_7_,
        node0_."description" as descript7_7_,
        node0_."image_url" as image_ur8_7_,
        node0_."left" as left9_7_,
        node0_."name" as name10_7_,
        node0_."right" as right11_7_,
        node0_."space_id" as space_i14_7_,
        node0_."state" as state12_7_,
        node0_."type" as type13_7_,
        node0_."user_group_id" as user_gr15_7_ 
    from
        "node" node0_ 
    left outer join
        "node_document" ftsdocumen1_ 
            on node0_."id"=ftsdocumen1_."id" 
    left outer join
        "user_group" usergroup2_ 
            on node0_."user_group_id"=usergroup2_."id" 
    left outer join
        "user_user_group" users3_ 
            on usergroup2_."id"=users3_."user_group_id" 
    left outer join
        "jhi_user" user4_ 
            on users3_."user_id"=user4_."id" 
    inner join
        "space" space5_ 
            on node0_."space_id"=space5_."id" 
    where
        space5_."state"=0 
        and node0_."state"=0 
        and (
            node0_."user_group_id" is null 
            or user4_."login"=?
        ) 
        and 1=1 
        and to_tsvector('english', document ) @@ plainto_tsquery( ? )=true 
    order by
        ts_rank(to_tsvector(ftsdocumen1_."document"),
        plainto_tsquery(?)) desc limit ?
```

Here is postresql database log:

```
2019-06-04 13:23:16.282 EEST [6820] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: BEGIN
select distinct node0_."id" as col_0_0_, ts_rank(to_tsvector(ftsdocumen1_."document"), plainto_tsquery($1)) as col_1_0_, node0_."id" as id1_7_, node0_."created_by" as created_2_7_, node0_."created_date" as created_3_7_, node0_."last_modified_by" as last_mod4_7_, node0_."last_modified_date" as last_mod5_7_, node0_."alias" as alias6_7_, node0_."description" as descript7_7_, node0_."image_url" as image_ur8_7_, node0_."left" as left9_7_, node0_."name" as name10_7_, node0_."right" as right11_7_, node0_."space_id" as space_i14_7_, node0_."state" as state12_7_, node0_."type" as type13_7_, node0_."user_group_id" as user_gr15_7_ from "node" node0_ inner join "node_document" ftsdocumen1_ on node0_."id"=ftsdocumen1_."id" left outer join "user_group" usergroup2_ on node0_."user_group_id"=usergroup2_."id" left outer join "user_user_group" users3_ on usergroup2_."id"=users3_."user_group_id" left outer join "jhi_user" user4_ on users3_."user_id"=user4_."id" inner join "space" space5_ on node0_."space_id"=space5_."id" where space5_."state"=0 and node0_."state"=0 and (node0_."user_group_id" is null or user4_."login"=$2) and 1=1 and to_tsvector('english', document ) @@ plainto_tsquery( $3 )=true order by ts_rank(to_tsvector(ftsdocumen1_."document"), plainto_tsquery($4)) desc limit $5 node0_."id" as col_0_0_, ts_rank(to_tsvector(ftsdocumen1_."document"), plainto_tsquery($1)) as col_1_0_, node0_."id" as id1_7_, node0_."created_by" as created_2_7_, node0_."created_date" as created_3_7_, node0_."last_modified_by" as last_mod4_7_, node0_."last_modified_date" as last_mod5_7_, node0_."alias" as alias6_7_, node0_."description" as descript7_7_, node0_."image_url" as image_ur8_7_, node0_."left" as left9_7_, node0_."name" as name10_7_, node0_."right" as right11_7_, node0_."space_id" as space_i14_7_, node0_."state" as state12_7_, node0_."type" as type13_7_, node0_."user_group_id" as user_gr15_7_ from "node" node0_ inner join "node_document" ftsdocumen1_ on node0_."id"=ftsdocumen1_."id" left outer join "user_group" usergroup2_ on node0_."user_group_id"=usergroup2_."id" left outer join "user_user_group" users3_ on usergroup2_."id"=users3_."user_group_id" left outer join "jhi_user" user4_ on users3_."user_id"=user4_."id" inner join "space" space5_ on node0_."space_id"=space5_."id" where space5_."state"=0 and node0_."state"=0 and (node0_."user_group_id" is null or user4_."login"=$2) and 1=1 and to_tsvector('english', document ) @@ plainto_tsquery( $3 )=true order by ts_rank(to_tsvector(ftsdocumen1_."document"), plainto_tsquery($4)) desc limit $5
2019-06-04 13:23:16.323 EEST [6820] LOG:  execute S_3: ROLLBACK
```

I traced it down to Hickari sending this, which executes perfectly fine when copied to a database without any change to the query!

```sql
select distinct node0_."id" as col_0_0_,
 ts_rank(to_tsvector(ftsdocumen1_."document"), plainto_tsquery('super')) as col_1_0_,
 node0_."id" as id1_7_,
 node0_."created_by" as created_2_7_,
 node0_."created_date" as created_3_7_,
 node0_."last_modified_by" as last_mod4_7_,
 node0_."last_modified_date" as last_mod5_7_,
 node0_."alias" as alias6_7_,
 node0_."description" as descript7_7_,
 node0_."image_url" as image_ur8_7_,
 node0_."left" as left9_7_,
 node0_."name" as name10_7_,
 node0_."right" as right11_7_,
 node0_."space_id" as space_i14_7_,
 node0_."state" as state12_7_,
 node0_."type" as type13_7_,
 node0_."user_group_id" as user_gr15_7_ 
 from "node" node0_ 
 inner join "node_document" ftsdocumen1_ on node0_."id"=ftsdocumen1_."id" 
 left outer join "user_group" usergroup2_ on node0_."user_group_id"=usergroup2_."id" 
 left outer join "user_user_group" users3_ on usergroup2_."id"=users3_."user_group_id" 
 left outer join "jhi_user" user4_ on users3_."user_id"=user4_."id" inner join "space" space5_ on node0_."space_id"=space5_."id" 
 where space5_."state"=0 and node0_."state"=0 and (node0_."user_group_id" is null or user4_."login"='firstname.lastname') and 1=1 and 
 to_tsvector('english', document ) @@ plainto_tsquery( 'super' )=true 
 order by ts_rank(to_tsvector(ftsdocumen1_."document"), plainto_tsquery('super')) desc limit 30
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1044085) people say that it is a Hibernate bug when order by with parameter doesn't work and it should be fixed in version 6.

Meanwhile solution which worked for me was ordering by column number in selection list like that:

```java
.orderBy(builder.desc(builder.literal(2)));
```